# Combine wins and losses in same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm struggling to nail down a SQL Server 2012 query I'm trying to write and hoping somebody can help me out. This is what I currently have as my query:

```
 --home wins
 select NULL as roadlosses, Count(t1.TeamName) as homewins, t1.TeamName from scores s
 inner join games g
 on g.GameID=s.GameID
 inner join teams t1
 on t1.TeamID=g.HomeTeam
 inner join teams t2
 on t2.Teamid=g.AwayTeam
 where (s.hometotalruns - s.awaytotalruns) > 0 and t1.TeamName = 'Pirates'
 group by t1.teamname

 UNION
 --road losses

 select Count(t2.TeamName) as roadlosses, NULL, t2.TeamName from scores s
 inner join games g
 on g.GameID=s.GameID
 inner join teams t1
 on t1.TeamID=g.HomeTeam
 inner join teams t2
 on t2.Teamid=g.AwayTeam
 where (s.hometotalruns - s.awaytotalruns) > 0 and t2.TeamName = 'Pirates' 
 group by t2.TeamName
```

This gets me close with the results being:

```
 roadlosses    homewins     teamname
 NULL            41          Pirates
 26             NULL         Pirates
```

I want this to return only 1 row, eliminating the `NULL`s, but I just can't seem to get it.

I tried looking at [this](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=140319) but it's not quite exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this as a single query, with conditional aggregation.  I think this is the query:

```
 select sum(case when (s.hometotalruns - s.awaytotalruns) > 0 and t2.TeamName = 'Pirates' 
                 then 1 else 0
            end) as roadlosses,
        sum(case when (s.hometotalruns - s.awaytotalruns) > 0 and t1.TeamName = 'Pirates'
                 then 1 else 0
            end) as homewins,
        'Pirates' as TeamName
 from scores s
 inner join games g
 on g.GameID=s.GameID
 inner join teams t1
 on t1.TeamID=g.HomeTeam
 inner join teams t2
 on t2.Teamid=g.AwayTeam
 where 'Pirates' in (t1.TeamName, t2.teamName);
```

Comment: awesome thank you - i had to change the last line to where 'Pirates' in(t1.TeamName, t2.teamName);

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the team name you're after, I think it makes sense to pull that out instead of referring to it throughout the query continuously, and not having to join to the teams table at all in the main query. If the team name is unique (I certainly hope it is!), this should be a very inexpensive seek.

```
-- this would be your input parameter:
DECLARE @TeamName VARCHAR(32) = 'Pirates';

-- the rest would be the code:
DECLARE @TeamID INT;
SELECT @TeamID = TeamID FROM dbo.Teams WHERE TeamName = @TeamName;

;WITH x AS 
(
   SELECT 
     location = CASE g.HomeTeam WHEN @TeamID THEN 'H' ELSE 'A' END,
     run_diff = s.hometotalruns - s.awaytotalruns
   FROM dbo.Scores AS s
   INNER JOIN dbo.Games AS g
   ON s.GameID = g.GameID
   WHERE @TeamID IN (g.HomeTeam, g.AwayTeam)
)
SELECT 
 RoadLosses = COUNT(CASE WHEN location = 'A' AND run_diff > 0 THEN 1 END),
 HomeWins   = COUNT(CASE WHEN location = 'H' AND run_diff > 0 THEN 1 END),
 TeamName   = @TeamName  
FROM x;
```

Comment: I definitely like this approach too and will probably end up turning this into a stored procedure.  +1